# PHP Multiple Iteration Hashing

Tags: php, hash, sha1

When looking through my PHP code, I found that the area of my code where I performed a multiple iteration hash of my code was causing problems, not allowing the page to be loaded (when I tried to load register.php, it would simply load a white blank page). I can't seem to find the error in my code though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function RandomString($length) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$code = RandomString(25);
mail($email, "Your code for the Assassin game.", "Your code is: $code");
$salt = RandomString(8);
$hashedcode = "";
for($i=0;$i<5;i++){
    $hashedcode = sha1($hashedcode.$code.$salt);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last loop, which seems pointless anyway since it's just overwriting `$hashedcode`, will never end because you're incrementing a constant `i` instead of the `$i` var, and so `$i` remains 0, which is forever less than 5, yielding that condition infinitely true:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;i++){
    $hashedcode = sha1($hashedcode.$code.$salt);
}
```

should be

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $hashedcode = sha1($hashedcode.$code.$salt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that! Also, doesn't the last loop, in its corrected form, make a multiple-iteration salted hash of $code?

Comment: It is, but it's one of those things I've personally felt was too little too late. False sense of security, if you will.

Comment: @CMUEngineer - Five iterations won't seriously slow down brute-forcing. If you want an iterated hash then you should better use BCrypt using PHPs [password_hash](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. In your case with a 25 character string (a very strong password), it is safe enough to calculate a single SHA256 hash though. If you want to increase security i would suggest that you work on the randomness of the code instead.